# How to hide panel upon button being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the submit button is clicked I want the `panel-default` to have `opacity: 0` for that respective `inspiration`:

```
<% @inspirations.each do |inspiration| %> # List of featured inspirations for user to choose from
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user.inspirations.build) do |f| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default"> # Once user clicks pushpin I want the inspiration he clicked to get opacity 0
      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'button-bitches') do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: inspiration.name %>
      <%= inspiration.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### UPDATE 1

I can now make the button disappear when clicked, but I still can't get the panel to disappear.

```
<script>
    $('.button-bitches').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }
    });
</script>
```

**css**

```
.panel-default.active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-bitches.active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

This will give `.panel-default` opacity 0, which is what I want, but it will do it for every `inspiration`. I want it to just to do for the inspiration that was clicked.

```
$('.button-bitches').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.panel-default').removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $('.panel-default').addClass('active')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that the button is the child of the `panel-default`, you should try this:

```
$('.button-bitches').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parents('.panel-default').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parents('.panel-default').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

This could also be shortened to:

```
$('.button-bitches').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active')
                       .parents('.panel-default').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active')
                       .parents('.panel-default').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Or you could toggle the `active` class

```
        $('.button-bitches').click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('active')
                       .parents('.panel-default').toggleClass('active');
        });
```

PS: I didn't test it, but I am pretty sure it will work as long as the `button` is the child of the `.panel-default` and your `CSS` is correct.

Comment: I got another javascript problem if you would mind offering some input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464849/j-rendered-collection-select-outputs-html-tags. No one seems to have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

could please try this one.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="hidepanel">....</div>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" onclick="hidediv();"></span>
```

Javascript file:

```
function hidediv() {
document.getElementById("hidepanel").style.opacity = "0";}
```

Please change css like this

```
.panel-default:active {
  opacity: 0;
 }

 .button-bitches:active {
    opacity: 0;
 }
```

Comment: you should put inside of script tag only <script>function hidediv() {
document.getElementById("hidepanel").style.opacity = "0";}</script>

Comment: .panel-default:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-bitches:active {
  opacity: 0;
}                                                                                                                           can you please try like this

Comment: because u gave like this .panel-default.active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-bitches.active {
  opacity: 0;
}

Comment: That makes no difference `.active` would be correct. I'm not using it in the traditional CSS sense. Replace `active` with `chocolate`. This needs a period before it.